# File access time not updated

Tags: linux

I just have viewed `/etc/resolv.conf` file using a `cat` command (or opening it with mcedit). Now when i list file details using `ls -ul` the "access time" doesn't change/update - have the same, old value. It's strange since for any other files "access time" is updated after cat.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8842/109842) suggests that many filesystems disable updating the atime for performance reasons, perhaps the case for you?

Answer (score 1):

Invoke `df /etc/resolv.conf` and note under what mountpoint it exists. Example from my Kubuntu:

```
$ df /etc/resolv.conf
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             806600  9660    796940   2% /run
```

Surprisingly my `resolv.conf` is under `/run`. True:

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 24  2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Then we need to know its mount options:

```
$ mount | grep " /run "
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=806600k,mode=755)
```

Pay attention to `atime`-related option. In my case this is `relatime`. [`man 8 mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) explains:

> `relatime`
>   Update inode access times relative to modify or change time. Access time is only updated if the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change time. (Similar to `noatime`, but doesn't break `mutt` or other applications that need to know if a file has been read since the last time it was modified.)

(Check the rest of `*atime` options to have a full picture.)

`relatime` is very common nowadays. It saves frequent writing yet still provides `atime` to programs that need it. In my Kubuntu only these mounts don't use `relatime`:

```
$ mount | grep -v relatime
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
```

Probably you broadly use `relatime` too.

> It's strange since for any other files "access time" is updated after `cat`.

Maybe "the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change time", so the `atime` was updated. Or "other files" are under a different mountpoint (e.g. with `strictatime` option). Note my `resolv.conf` is on a different filesystem than the whole `/etc/` (`/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to elsewhere), so in general you shouldn't even assume that "files" in the same directory are on the same filesystem, under the same mountpoint with the same options.

Whatever your setup is, now you know how to investigate the issue.